# Can't connect my windows 8.1 machine to an external display

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a touch screen all in one desktop, running 8.1. I'm trying to connect my benq external display via dvi or hdmi cables.

I've plugged the power cable into the external screen and connected it via dvi to my PC. The PC picked up the fact there was another screen but the screen was saying no signal.

I then tried removing the dvi cable and putting hdmi instead, the PC did not pick up any change even after both had been restarted, however the screen said no cable connected.

I've made sure the screen has been on the right settings however no luck.

I then accidentally clicked only use other screen, now my PC is saying no signal, as is the screen, even when I've unplugged it, and now I'm pretty much locked out.

Comment: "I've made sure the screen has been on the right settings however no luck." which settings? Screen Resolution settings? Was the monitor being detected there?
"I then accidentally clicked only use other screen, now my PC is saying no signal, as is the screen, even when I've unplugged it, and now I'm pretty much locked out." It should've displayed a "revert settings?" confirmation afterwards with a countdown timer, in case you mess up. Did the settings not revert? Either way, I think if you unplug the monitor and restart the computer it should revert.

Comment: The screen has input mode buttons, I made sure it was using the right one. There was no option to revert. I've unplugged it, restarted twice and still get no signal.

Comment: How is your primary monitor connected? Can you connect it to a 2nd slot instead? The option to revert should've been automatic 15s after the fatal change was made... did you panic?

Comment: My primary monitor is an all in one PC, it's not connected to anything external. No it didn't revert as I accidentally did it by using the win 8 charms

Comment: Ok I've got my main screen back, I managed to change it blindly

Comment: Yeah I was about to suggest getting another Windows 8 machine and attempt to navigate the settings with the keyboard, that's a big fix. Good job.

Comment: Thanks, although my external displays still not working..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Instructions On Configuring Dual Monitors For Windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/579851/need-instructions-on-configuring-dual-monitors-for-windows-8)

Answer (score -1):

### I have the same issue

My machine has Intel and NVIDIA cards.

> I tried many times to re-install the Nvidia driver and changed to the new version but cannot resolve this issue. Then I changed to a new method. I changed the Intel driver instead and got a newer version. It worked for me!

---

I fixed it by:

1. disable "Intel HD Graphics driver" (not Nvidia)
2. install the "HD Graphics diver" with new version (download from Intel website)
3. restart your machine